# Defining vertical tangent lines

Tags: calculus, soft-question, definition

In looking at the definition of vertical tangent lines in some popular calculus texts,

I noticed that there are a few different definitions for this term, including the following:

A function $f$ has a vertical tangent line at $a$ if

$\textbf{1)}$ $\;f$ is continuous at $a$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\;\lvert f^{\prime}(x)\rvert=\infty$

$\textbf{2)}$ $\;f$ is continuous at $a$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f^{\prime}(x)=\infty$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f^{\prime}(x)=-\infty$

$\textbf{3)}$ $\;\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\pm\infty$

I would like to ask if there is a standard definition of this term, and whether or not the definition should include continuity at $a$ and should not include the situation where the graph has a vertical cusp at $a$.

---

Here are some examples where these definitions lead to different conclusions:

a) $\;f(x)=x^{2/3}$

b) $\;f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{, if }x>0\\0&\mbox{, if }x=0\\-1&\mbox{, if }x<0\end{cases}$

(This [question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10445) has also been posted on Math Educators Stack Exchange.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking as a geometer, I want "tangency" to be independent of the coordinate system. Particularly, if $f$ is a real-valued function of one variable defined in some neighborhood of $a$, and if $f$ is invertible in some neighborhood of $a$, then the line $x = a$ should be tangent to the graph $y = f(x)$ at $a$ if and only if the line $y = b = f(a)$ is tangent to the graph $y = f^{-1}(x)$ at $b$.

For an elementary calculus course I'd want:

- $f$ continuous in some neighborhood of $a$;
- $f$ invertible in some neighborhood of $a$;
- $f'(a) = \pm\infty$, i.e., $(f^{-1})'(b) = 0$ (the graph $y = f^{-1}(x)$ has $y = a$ as horizontal tangent).

---

Condition 1 does not guarantee invertibility near $a$ (as the cusp shows), so in my book it's out.

Condition 2 implies all three items of my wish list. ($f$ is implicitly assumed differentiable in some neighborhood of $a$; the derivative condition guarantees the derivative doesn't change sign in some neighborhood of $a$, and that $f'(a) = \pm\infty$.)

Condition 3 does not imply continuity (as the step function shows), so it's out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I was interested to see what a geometer thinks about this.

Comment: You're very welcome; it's a good question! As you'll note, I made no effort to formulate the most general criterion for a vertical tangent line. In practice, I believe one normally wants to speak of vertical tangents in the context of real-analytic curves. Even in that setting, the notion of a "function" isn't invariant under swapping axes, unfortunately, so getting "the right definition" isn't a simple matter of saying "the flipped curve has a horizontal tangent". Assuming invertibility and continuity seems not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a completely accurate answer, but it works for enough of the time that I'll post it anyway.

You know that in normal circumstances of $y$ as a function of $x$ where you want to find a **HORIZONTAL** tangent line, one way is to find

${dy \over dx} = 0$

and solve for values of $x$ for which this is the case (note: the function and its derivative must be continuous at the points where the derivative equals 0 to warrant a horizontal tangent.)

In reality, the equation above is asking "at what points $x$ does $y$ not
change when $x$ changes?"

But if I'm looking at a **VERTICAL** tangent line, I'm really asking the equation "at what points $x$ does $x$ not change when $y$ changes?"

So then instead of $dy \over dx$, I want to know instead when

${dx \over dy} = 0$

for which both $x$ and its derivative are continuous at the points where ${dx \over dy} = 0$.

Vertical tangents are more difficult to define when we take all y as a function of x because (unless the function is one-to-one) it is difficult to define a vertical cusp. Instead, if we define a vertical tangent line to exist when:

- $x$ is continuous and
- its derivative $dx \over dy$ is continuous

we can rule out vertical cusps, which do not have a continuous derivative.

While I don't know of a good standard definition, I hope this one I was taught helps you understand what vertical tangents are.